# How to use classification Learner in my environment?

Tags: matlab, multiclass-classification, image-preprocessing

> I am working on facial expression recognition. i made a dataset
>   contain features & classes of 213 images.

- Step1: Each row of my dataset represents the features of 1 image. so
  for 213 images 213 rows
- Step2: the last column represents classes like; 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
- Q1: when i run classification learner and the cross validation is
  checked the accuracy is very low.
- Q2: when i run classification learner and the cross validation is not
  checked  the accuracy is good for all classifiers.

I dont understand why? please help me? if someone has already experienced.

Answer (score 0):

This is called overfitting. If you don't cross-validate, your classifier is likely to learn the in-sample cases without being able to generalize.

To find out you need to have a training set, a test set (the cross-validation set), and a validation set to check how well does your classifier generalizes to new cases.

Comment: if do have time please help me with this. classification learner takes only one file at at time. i import full dataset and run it. Can i divide training set, a test set.? Run it on both at a time or one.

Comment: i dont use any code iam using matlab classification learner app.

Comment: would you have a link for that app?

Comment: its the matlab builtin app at the App tab. or u can read the docs. here... https://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/classification-learner.html

Comment: I am not familiar with the app but I would say that you always have to stick with cross-validation. If your classifier performs poorly, tune the parameters of your model, try a different classifier (SVM, KNN etc..), try a different feature selection method, or a different cross-validation partition 3-fold vs 5-fold vs holdout etc..